# Calibrating a time of flight camera

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I have recently bought a time of flight camera, I have some experience in calibrating normal cameras, but I have no clue how to calibrate a time of flight camera. Can you please point out anything that can explain how to proper calibrate a time of flight camera?

[This](https://pmdtec.com/picofamily/assets/datasheet/Data-sheet-PMD_RD_Brief_CB_pico_flexx_V0201.pdf) is the ToF I currently have, and I'd like to implement something in openCV that allows me to calibrate it.

Update:

Just found [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9aea/151b4bb692f42a8cee94dd685a162ff62922.pdf) section 3 gives some insights about calibration.

Comment: I'm intrigued - do you care to describe what you plan to use it for please?

Comment: Essentially aligning a depth image with an RGB image, I think it's a classical problem, but I don't have a clue how to tackle it. Pretty sure there must be something around.

Comment: You could possibly image a kind of fish-net grid against a background that's far away. Your ToF should then essentially see a grid of squares. Then you could find the corners of these squares using OpenCV. Once you have the corner locations on the image plane your can input it to OpenCV's `CalibrateCamera` function and find the distortion model. My guess is that the grid should be larger than a fish net as the resolution is very low, maybe you could build one with PVC pipes. That said, I didn't even know these kinds of cameras existed, so this sound like a fun challenge!

Comment: Interesting approach, but that tof camera has also an IR camera embedded, I think the general approach is use such IR image for estimating parameters and from these somehow recover the tof camera parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Time of flight camera calibration is usually dependent on what you want to do with it in most cases you would like to measure the distance with it in that case there are two ways of calibrating the camera.
Method 1.phase sweep. In that case you have access to the phase offset of the camera or the light source in that case you sweep over all the phases you can sweep over and make a lookup table of expected vs recieved values, and that is it.
Method 2. Distance sweep. In that case you put a target and physically change the distance of that target and make a lookup table as above.

If lens calibration is what you want that is another story, but usually these cameras are quite well lens calibrated.

pitfalls:

1. When you do distance calibration ensure lights are turned off so that you don't get interference from other external lights.
2. If you choose to do lens calibration ensure that the material you are calibrating with is luminous enough in the IR region or the region you are using your light in.
   Extras.
   Sometimes people choose to fit a curve instead of just using a lookup table and honestly this is usually more accurate. Again, it depends on your application

If you can explain in details your application to me I can point you to a more useful resource.

Comment: If you could give me a reference or something I can read it would be great.

Comment: OK, this topic is quite complicated, I know because I worked with it for a bit. First I suggest that you read this paper
https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.9388&rep=rep1&type=pdf
Then This part of the documentation for opencv https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html
You have to be very careful and differentiate between depth calibration and 2D image calibration. Please note that the grey scale image for a depth sensor has to be recovered to do the the 2D calibration.

Comment: If you still have questions after that please go ahead and ask.
Note: Even after going through with the above I was not able to calibrate the sensor except after reading actual code like the code in the supplemental materials here 
https://light.informatik.uni-bonn.de/low-budget-transient-imaging-using-photonic-mixer-devices/
However, simply put the calibration is a lookup table. If these resources help please accept my answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links. One thing to know, I have some experience with camera calibration (like DLSR or phone cameras). However I have little experience with depth camera / ToF so I was wondering mainly how the calibration process changes based on the camera.

Comment: In that case the most important figure is figure 2 in the paper. Actually people usually call it the calibration curve.
I have worked with an older version of this camera. You can get quadrature values of the images you square and add them to get the amplitude you arctan their division to get the phase. However people usually just divide them and let the calibration matrix take care of the atan . In case you decide to use the atan please rememeber to use atan2